# Como pesquisar telefones com Autofilter em VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, excel-vba

Estou usando VBA para aplicar um filtro na coluna de números de telefone.

Os números de telefones são tratados de forma personalizada para ficar no modelo (XX) XXXXX-XXXX ou (XX) XXXX-XXXX

Eu pego o valor de uma célula e uso como o valor para a busca do filtro.

Segue o código:

```
If Not IsEmpty(Range("B7")) Then
Range("A12").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Range("B7").Value

End If
```

Não recebo retorno quando o valor possui formatação

Comment: Qual o comportamento que você esperava? O código não inclui nada que tenha relação com estar ou não formatado da forma X ou Y. O que esse trecho de código faz é apenas o seguinte: se a célula B7 não estiver vazia, vá ao filtro existente que abrange a célula A12, pegue a segunda coluna e configure para mostrar apenas os valores equivalentes a B7. Ele se comporta de alguma forma diferente desta? Dá alguma mensagem de erro?

Comment: Além disso, falta um "=" no parâmetro ```Criteria1```. Era pra ser ```Criteria1:=Range("B7").Value```

Comment: @CésarRodriguez Correto! Na verdade estou tentando encontrar uma forma de fazer a pesquisa para filtrar os valores com a formatação personalizada, eu tentei usar o NumberFormat mas também não obtive resultado pois ele estava retornando FALSE e não o numero formatado.
O resultado que obtenho é um filtro sem os símbolos que são utilizados na formatação personalizada, mas ainda não encontrei uma maneira de resolver isto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Após mais um pouco de pesquisa encontrei essa solução usando o `Strings.Format`, ele retorna uma `string` então dessa forma o VBA passa o valor exato com todos os símbolos no `AutoFilter`.

```
Dim NumTelefone As String
NumTelefone = Range("B7")
If Len(NumTelefone) > 10 Then
NumTelefone = Strings.Format(NumTelefone, "[<=9999999999] (##)#####-####")
Else
NumTelefone = Strings.Format(NumTelefone, "[<=9999999999] (##)####-####")
End If
```